# Why in function 'int main()' -> 's' may be used unitialized in this function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n,s;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        s += i;
    }

    cout << s;

    return 1;
}
```

Error :

```
suma_gauss.cpp: In function 'int main()':
suma_gauss.cpp:14:11: warning: 's' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  cout << s;

           ^
```

Comment: The error message is not saying that you are allowed to use `s` uninitialized, but that you may be doing it anyway. In this case, you are: you never set `s` to a specific value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not just a "maybe". `s` is used uninitialized in your code, always (maybe not in the loop, but latest at `cout << s;`). `s += i` is equivalent to `s = s + i;`, hence your code has undefined behavior.

PS: The compiler points you at `cout << s;` because depending on `n`, the loop may not be executed at all. However, it could (/should) have warned already for `s+=i;`.